# How to make search by multiline string?

Tags: phpstorm

Can I in PhpStorm 2021.2 to make search by multiline string, like :

```
   Facility
       ::orderBy()
       ...
```

If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just click on the "New Line" button to add the new line (see screenshots below).

**Alternatively** (if a text is already in the file) make a selection first and then hit the Find button -- the selected text will be inserted into the search field.

Local Find (in a current file):

[image]

Find in Files:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works, but how can I  make search withoiu considering spaces/tab chars at left from     ::orderBy() as in my example ?

Comment: Switch to RegEx mode and use appropriate pattern in that place (e.g. `.*` for any symbol appearing 0+ times; `\s+` for just whitespace symbols .. or whatever is more suitable for you)